# Debugging (Silverlight + PHP web service) application on VS2010

Tags: php, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging, nusoap

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Silverlight 4 and a PHP web service (NuSOAP). Everything works fine when I copy the XXXTestPage.html and the XXX.xap file to the remote server, and open the page in a web browser. I do have the "clientaccesspolicy.xml" file at the remote server, and that makes it work. So, the NuSOAP web service works fine not only from a tool like soapUI but also from my Silverlight application.
However, I'm unable to DEBUG my aplication in VS2010. I get an error saying "*CommunicationException was unhandled by user code. An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://xxxxxxxx/php/service.php'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.*"

So, my VS2010 solution has only one project, which is the Silverlight application. I do NOT use asp.net.

I was able to live without debugging for some time, but now the application is getting more complex, and I do need that.

Anyone knows how to approach this?

Thank you very much.

**Edit 1**. With Fiddler (and deleting all IE9 cached data before every experiment) I've seen this:
a) Outside VS2010, I see three HTTP sessions: one for the .html file, another one for the .xap file, and a final one for the service.php file. Everything works ok outside VS2010.
b) Inside VS2010 (trying to debug), I see only one HTTP session, for the clientaccesspolicy.xml file. I do see the answer, containing exactly this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from>
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Since there are no more HTTP sessions (where they should be, because the code calls the NuSOAP web service), it looks like there is something in the .xml file that VS2010 does not like. I copied that .xml from an MSDN page. Is there anything wrong with it? Doesn't it allow SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent? Thanks.

**Edit 2**. Got it! The "clientaccesspolicy.xml" file should contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

So, solved! I can debug now :-) Thanks anyway.

Comment: As you are not running ASP.Net, is your clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the root of your actual website, not just the application root? Use fiddler or other tools to view the traffic and see what is going on.

Comment: @HiTech Magic: yes, the xml file is in the root of my subdomain. I know it is in the right place, because the Silverlight application did not work until I moved it there. I'll use Fiddler to try to see what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: I added "Edit 1" to my question.